# Fancybox 3 For opening Vimeo clips

Tags: popup, fancybox, vimeo, clip

I'm trying to use Fancybox 3 for opening vimeo embedded clips. I've Tried to replace an online image herf with the vimeo url but it doesn't work, how can I fix it?

```
    <a class="fancybox" href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/179809192" data-fancybox >
    <img src="video_preview/berlin_preview.png" class="berlin_preview"></a>
```

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Your snippet works fine - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MvVpQd?editors=1000

Comment: @Janis thanks for the help!